# How to install ggplot2 for R to a custom lib directory

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, package

I want to use the `ggplot2` library for R installed in a custom `lib` folder, namely `~/.r`. After installing the library to my home directory through the command

```
> install.packages("ggplot2", lib="~/.r")
```

The output indicates that the installation was successful. However, loading the library does not seem to work properly:

```
> library(ggplot2, lib="~/.r")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
  call: loadNamespace(name)
  error: there is no package called ‘crayon’
```

The libary `crayon` seems to be installed, because there are files in the directory `~/.r/crayon`. Even trying to reinstall the library with the following command does not help

```
> remove.packages("crayon", lib="~/.r")
> install.packages("crayon", lib="~/.r")
```

I am able to use a personal library instead when installing without the `lib` parameter, but this installs to `~/R`, which I don't want.

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
...
> library(ggplot2)
```

Why is the `install.package` and `library` command with `lib="~/.r"` not working as expected? How can I use the custom `lib` path for R libraries in general and `ggplot2` more specifically?

Comment: Does `library(crayon, lib="~/.r")` work? I would guess that you simply need to use `.libPaths("~/.r")`, or take a look at, for example, [this page](https://zkamvar.github.io/blog/using-a-custom-library-in-r/) if you want a more lasting solution (i.e., not just for this R session). As a side note, usually "Why is [X] not working properly?" isn't the right question; it's usually "Why is [X] not working how I expect it to?"

Comment: Yes, that works. The link you provided seems nice, and seems to work. I'll have a look. I edited the question, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks, duckmayr. I adapted the commands to fit the question and answered it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from the [article linked by duckmayr](https://zkamvar.github.io/blog/using-a-custom-library-in-r/), the following solution worked for me:

```
> dir.create("~/.r/library", recursive = TRUE)
> cat("R_LIBS=~/.r/library", file = "~/.Renviron", append = TRUE)
```

Then after reloading it is indicated that the new `lib` path works as expected:

```
> .libPaths()
> [1] "/home/user/.r/library" "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Therefore, the following commands now make a persistent installation of `ggplot2` in the hidden folder `~/.r` and successfully load the library:

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
...
> library(ggplot2)
```